1970s teen underground city book
I read this book as a young teenager. It was about a scientist who developed a machine that could tunnel underground they made it so far and they discovered an ancient civilization. The civilization wasn’t human.
I can’t remember too much of the book, but I know there were two machines that were trying to reach the surface at the end of the book and one of the groups sabotaged the wrong machine, and the bad guys got permanently stuck when their machine failed. I think the name, Sol Was one of the characters. It’s been driving me crazy for years.

Going on a limb here, but could this be the Earthship Giganto series by Rolf Ulrici? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolf_Ulrici#Erdschiff_Giganto (sorry, German link). It's 1970s, but I read only the first four instalments. It has the scientist ("Professor Charivari") who built the ship, and a non-human antagonist ("Ragamuffin") living inside the Earth. I don't remember the other details you mention, but as I said, I didn't read the whole series.
